# Reemplazar valores de una tabla en relacion con otra?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, sql

Buenas tardes grupo mi consulta es la siguiente tengo estas tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla libros esta el campo lib_autor este campo tiene un monton de registros 3689 para ser exactos cada uno con su respectivo autor(pero estos se repiten) y lo que quiero es reemplazar esos nombres con la id almacenada en la tabla autores aut_id ya que en esta tabla cada autor tiene su id y no se repiten, me podrian decir algun query o algo que haga lo que busco se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Un libro tiene un solo autor verdad? y un autor puede tener varios libros cierto? pregunto para ayudarte con el query, por lo que veo si la relacion es de 1 a muchos lo que tienes que hacer es crea un campo en la tabla libros donde coloques el id del autor y no su nombre, si es asi como digo avisame para responder abajo con el query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es agregar la columna "lib_autor_id" a la tabla "libros".

```
ALTER TABLE `libros` ADD `lib_autor_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `lib_titulo`;
```

Después, debes hacer la relación entre las tablas "libros" y "autores".

```
UPDATE `libros` l LEFT JOIN `autores` a ON l.lib_autor = a.aut_autor
SET l.lib_autor_id = a.aut_id;
```

Y por último, después de asegurarte de que la columna "lib_autor" de la tabla "libros" ya no es necesaria, la eliminas.

```
ALTER TABLE `libros` DROP `lib_autor`;
```

**IMPORTANTE:** No olvides hacer un backup de la base de datos antes de modificarla.

Comment: muchas gracias si sirvio te lo agradezco un monton